# Exploding gradients in an LSTM network

Tags: vb.net, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

I have created my own lstm neural network in vb.net. From what I've read lstm networks are not meant to suffer from the effects of exploding/vanishing gradients. However, after a while all the gradients will increase to the maximum. Changing the rate only affects the time taken for this to happen. Is there anything that can cause exploding gradients in an lstm network?

I'm using RMSProp with momentum to update weights with a sequence size ranging from 32 to 64. Also includes peephole connectors with the training data in the range of [0,1].

I based it off the paper, LSTM: A space search odyssey

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a LSTM in pytorch. It helped to clip the gradient.
Additionally you could try to change the learning rate.